# How to prepare release version with SystemJS and Gulp?

Tags: typescript, gulp, angular, systemjs

I use SystemJS in my Angular2 project. I use tsconfig file for TypeScript. I want to use gulp to concat and minify my code for production version. I am having an issues with concating the code: each time I try to concat files I get either 'angular' not defined or 'system' not defined. I tried to modify the order that I try to load my files from node modules, however I did not succeeded.

I was wondering if any of you had this issues, and found an answer to it?

Here is my gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
            .....


var paths = {
    dist: 'dist',
    vendor: {
        js: [
            'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
            'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
            'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js'
             ...
        ],
        css: []
},
    app: {
        templates: [
            'app/**/*.html',
            '!node_modules/*.html'
        ],
        scripts: [
            'app/**/*.ts',
            'app/config.ts',
            'app/app.ts'
        ]
    }
};

var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
    out: 'Whatever.js'
});

gulp.task('dev:build:templates', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.app.templates)
        .pipe(ngHtml2Js({
            moduleName: 'Whatever',
            declareModule: false
        }))
        .pipe(concat("Whatever.tpls.min.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});
gulp.task('prod:build:templates', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.app.templates)
        .pipe(minifyHtml({
            empty: true,
            spare: true,
            quotes: true
        }))
        .pipe(ngHtml2Js({
            moduleName: 'whatever',
            declareModule: false
        }))
        .pipe(concat(paths.appName + ".tpls.min.js"))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});

gulp.task('dev:build:scripts', function () {
    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write({
            sourceRoot: '/app'
        }))
        .pipe(concat('whatever.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});

gulp.task('dev:build:styles', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.app.styles)
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/css'));
});
gulp.task('dev:build:vendor', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.vendor.js)
        .pipe(concat('vendor.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist))
});

gulp.task('dev:build', [
    'dev:build:vendor',
    'dev:build:templates',
    'dev:build:scripts',
    'dev:build:styles',
], function () {
});
```

This is how I load my files:

```
   <script src="vendor.min.js"></script>
   <script src="Whatever.js"></script>
   <script src="Whatever.tpls.min.js"></script>
```

And here are the erors that I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unexpected anonymous System.register call.(anonymous function) @ vendor.min.js:2680load.metadata.format @ vendor.min.js:3220oldModule @ vendor.min.js:3749(anonymous function) @ vendor.min.js:2411SystemJSLoader.register @ vendor.min.js:2636(anonymous function) @ Whatever.js:2
Whatever.tpls.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, sorry, didnt realized that

Comment: sharing some of your code would also help in finding your problem.

Comment: @toskv, which part of code are you interested in? gulp file? structure of my files after the gulp tasks?

Comment: gulp  file and filestructure would be a good start. :)

Comment: Sure, I will edit my question now

Comment: Make sure you load angular and systemjs first.

Comment: @maxisam thats exactly what I do.It still throws an error

Comment: Well, check your browser console and see if you are really pointing at right path.

Comment: @toskv, I've uploaded my gulp

Comment: @maxisam, all of the files are there, and indeed, it seems that everything is pointing in the right direction

Comment: i wouldn't bundle them as vendor.js. Try to load them separately and see if you load them in correct sequence.

Comment: @maxisam, It indeed works when I am not bundling them (in my development version). However, for the release, I would like to bundle them. The order, which I am using for development, is the same as order of loading them in the gulp, so it shouldn't have any impact on the project, right?

Comment: The order looks fine, but check the output file and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: BTW, I think angular2-polyfills.js should load first, but it is not really your problem here.

Comment: The TypeScript compiler doesn't output the names of your modules so you have to rely on the file names to get the module names. If you concatenate the files together you just have a bunch of anonymous modules in a file that SystemJs doesn't know when to load. I believe you have to use the SystemJs build tool if you want to bundle your files https://github.com/systemjs/builder . I've never been able to successfully get it working though.

Comment: Very similar answer is here [Build Angular2 HTML and TypeScript to a single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867660/build-angular2-html-and-typescript-to-a-single-file/35868706#35868706)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You will get " Unexpected anonymous System.register call" because the references are not being loaded in the correct order. I use JSPM to properly build my angular app for production.  There are 4 parts to the process.

Part 1:  Compile your typescript files

```js
var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var tsProject = ts.createProject("./App/tsconfig.json");
gulp.task("compile:ts", function () {
    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));
    tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest("./wwwroot/app"));

});
```

Part 2:  Configure config.js (to tell JSPM how to bundle your app):

```js
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  paths: {
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "node_modules*": "node_modules/*"
  },
  map: {
    'app': 'app',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular'
  },
  packages: {
    'app': { main: 'bootDesktop.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/compiler': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/core': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/http': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/platform-browser': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/router': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/router-deprecated': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/testing': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/upgrade': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  }


});
```

Part 3:  Use gulp-jspm-build to bundle up your app (I was previously using gulp-jspm but it was causing errors, so I switched to gulp-jspm-build):

```js
var jspm = require('gulp-jspm-build');
gulp.task("jspm_bundle", function () {
return jspm({
    bundleOptions: {
        minify: true,
        mangle: false
    },
    bundleSfx: true,
    bundles: [
        { src: './wwwroot/app/appBoot.js', dst: 'boot.bundle.min.js' }
    ]
})
.pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/js-temp'));


});
//this will create a file called boot.bundle.min.js
//note I have set jspm to create a self-executing bundle
//I put mangle to false because mangling was causing errors
```

4:  Now concat all your already minified assets:

```js
gulp.task("min:js", ["jspm_bundle"], function () {
    //this only concats boot.bundle.min.js
    //and dependencies.min.js which has already been minified such as es6-shim.js
    var files = [
        "./wwwroot/js-temp/dependencies.min.js",
        "./wwwroot/js-temp/boot.bundle.min.js"
    ];

    return gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(concat("boot.bundle.min.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./wwwroot/js"));

});
```

Finally, put one nice tidy script reference into your index.html:

```html
<script src="~/js/boot.bundle.min.js"> </script>
```

One of the nice features of this approach is that your bundled app will only contain the assets that are actually referenced in you import statements (jspm won't bundle it if you don't need it).

UPDATE:  Revised config.js to conform to a Angular 2.0-rc.0 appp

UPDATE 2:  tsconfig.json looks like this:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noLib": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this in coulpe of hours, as I am afk right now

Comment: You're welcome.  The trickiest part was figuring out the "map" arguments in the config.json file.  You don't need to have jspm import angular2 again, just reference whats already in the node_modules folder.

Comment: @brando I think it shold be "config.js" instead of "config.json".

Comment: @brando Are you leaving angular2 as an npm dependency so that the typescript compiler can find it? I've been struggling to get jspm working for that reason.

Comment: @reblace yes I leave angular2 as a npm dependency.  but when you are bundling with jspm (at least in my approach) angular is ALREADY transpiled into js, so jspm does not worry about typescript (although the jspm cli also could manage that task too).  In the config.js file, you tell jspm where this dependency (and others) live in your file structure and what file types you are bundling (e.g. js or ts).

Comment: am now using gulp-jspm-build instead of gulp-jspm, which was throwing errors.  Answer updated

Comment: @brando, since the question get so much attention, could you provide support for reflect-metadata? when I try to follow the guide, my console logs 'Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators'

Comment: hi @uksz you need to include Reflect.js as a part of the dependencies.min.js bundle as mentioned in step 4

Comment: @brando: Could you please post how your tsconfig.json looks like?

Comment: @PankajKapare I posted the tsconfig.json file

Comment: @brando: Thanks. I implemented build successfully. It helped lot.

Comment: I was using import().then(function(module){module.init()}) to initalize components when they were loaded. But when I bundle the component (not one big app, one bundle per page) and then do the same I get an error that init() isn't a function. How do people initialize modules when they are loaded?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SystemJS Builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder)

as easy as this

```
var path = require("path");
var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');

// optional constructor options
// sets the baseURL and loads the configuration file
var builder = new Builder('path/to/baseURL', 'path/to/system/config-file.js');

builder
.bundle('local/module.js', 'outfile.js')
.then(function() {
  console.log('Build complete');
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Build error');
  console.log(err);
});
```

you can look at the full setup in my [starter project](https://github.com/antonybudianto/angular2-starter)

Comment: Above example must be used together with SystemJS since it still needs the loader. If you prefer for standalone bundle, then use `.buildStatic` and put the bundle in script tag

Comment: Antony Budianto, i tried your starter project for creating angular 2 rc 4 project. when i modified some contents, i was not able to create a build file due to some error / test failed. If you can provide a basic skeleton of the build process / starter project with the very basic features like without test cases...  very very basis skeleton, that help me to learn from the basic. Angular 2 they provided half boiled web pack build process. While i am searching for the help of getting the build process for angular 2 rc4, i come to know many persons have same problems. So plz help us

Comment: Antony Budianto,  is the query which i posted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610209/how-do-i-actually-create-a-distributional-app-from-angular-2-rc4-typescript

Comment: So what should the path be for the System.import call in a scenario like this? Is it the path to the outfile.js?

Answer (score 0):

I think we found the root cause of this. Honestly, I have been there before so the way I trace this type of issue are

1. Check if angular & systemjs are loaded beforehand.
2. Check if they are really loaded. no 404 surprise. (It sounds stupid but shit happens)
3. If you bundle libraries as vender.js make sure they are bundle in correct sequence. Check the output file and see if they are concat as the way you expect.