# Build Angular2 HTML and TypeScript to a single file

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs, systemjs-builder

I'm putting together an app (Large scale) using Angular2 and TypeScript.  It will need to be divided into numerous projects and each project will have numerous components each with a `.html` view, `.css` stylesheet and `.ts` logic / class.

I would like each project to compile to a single `*.js` file and be copied to a host website which will run in IIS.  This would be similar to how a WPF or Silverlight app is built with the `.xaml` files all getting compiled into the `.dll`.

I've had a look around the web and am able to get the `.ts` files to build to a single `.js` file using the `--outFile` option.  But this doesn't help me with the `.html` files or the `css`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated even if it's to say that what I'm asking is impossible :-)

Stephen

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're using the default Angular2 `tsconfig.json` with [SystemJS loader](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs):

```
"module": "system",
"moduleResolution": "node",
...
```

You can leave all the heavy work on [SystemJS Build Tool](https://github.com/systemjs/builder). This is for example how I do it in my projects using `gulp`:

1. **Compile *.ts and inline *.html templates**

   I'm using [`gulp-angular-embed-templates`](https://github.com/laxa1986/gulp-angular-embed-templates) right away to inline all `templateUrl` into `template` strings (this plugin works with both Angular 1.* and Angular 2).

   ```
   var tsc = require('gulp-typescript');
   var tsProject = tsc.createProject('tsconfig.json');
   var embedTemplates = require('gulp-angular-embed-templates');

   gulp.task('app.build', function () {
       var tsResult = gulp.src('app/src/**/*.ts', {base: './app/src'})
           .pipe(embedTemplates()) // inline templates
           .pipe(tsc(tsProject));

       return tsResult.js
           .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
   });
   ```

   This will generate many [anonymous System.register modules](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/system-api.md) in `build/js` directory. All of them will have their `templateUrl` inlined already.
2. **Bundle everything into a single `.js` file**

   I use [SystemJS Build Tool](https://github.com/systemjs/builder) for this because I think it's way easier than using for example webpack. So, I have another gulp task for this to automate the process:

   ```
   var SystemBuilder = require('systemjs-builder');

   gulp.task('app.systemjs.bundle', function () {
       var builder = new SystemBuilder('build/js, {
           paths: {
               '*': '*.js'
           },
           meta: {
               'angular2/*': {
                   build: false
               },
               'rxjs/*': {
                   build: false
               }
           }
       });

       return builder.bundle('main', 'build/js/app.bundle.js');
   });
   ```

   The builder takes the same options as [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) so check their [Config API](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md).

   Calling `builder.bundle('main', ...)` searches for `main.js` (which is my initial script with Angular's `bootstrap` call. It's the same file you can see [in the 5 min quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)) because I append `.js` to all paths searched by the builder. This is because when you import a module in TS you usually call:

   ```
   import {ModalResultComponent} from './modal-result.component';
   ```

   which is compiled as `./modal-result.component` dependency and it doesn't care about the file extension. That's why I had to add `*.js` to all paths to help builder find all compiled JavaScript files.

   The `meta` options just tell the builder to ignore dependencies that I don't want to bundle. That's Angular2 itself and `rxjs` library because I include `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` in `main.ts`.

   This generates a single `app.bundle.js` file with all modules registered as named modules using [System.register](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/system-api.md#systemregistername--deps-declare).
3. **Using our `app.bundle.js`**

   The last part is a piece of cake. We just import the default Angular2 stuff and then use [`bundle` option](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#bundle) to tell SystemJS where're all our dependencies.

   ```
   <script>
   System.config({
       packages: {
           '/web': {
               format: 'register',
               defaultExtension: 'js'
           }
       },
       bundles: {
           '/web/app.bundle': ['main']
       }
   });
   System.import('main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
   </script>
   ```

   When we call `System.import('main')` it in fact first downloads `/web/app.bundle.js` and registers all modules in the package and after that it imports modules `main` with our Angular2 bootstrap.

   And that's it!

You actually don't need to use `gulp` at all and do everything with pure `node` script.

Bundling CSS files is easy with things like [cssnano](https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano) and I'm sure you can find tutorials on how to use it everywhere.

I'm sure there're other ways to the the same thing. Angular2 is designed not to restrict you to use just one technology. However, using SystemJS seems to me to be the easiest way because it uses the same module system as Angular2 by default.

I'm sure you could use also for example `commonjs` format but that would require you to use also some polyfill for `require()` loader, but I haven't tried it yet. I belive [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) might be also worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide such a comprehensive answer!

Comment: I have the following error in the app.build task Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign' at ChildClass.utils.extend.init (C:\SourceControl\GIT\Web\TorFx.Web.Site.NewBusiness\src\TorFx.Web.Site.NewBusiness\node_modules\gulp-angular-embed-templates\lib\ProcessorEngine.js:6:30)

Comment: @kernowcode: It's a know issue, right now you need min. node v4 which supports ES6: https://github.com/laxa1986/gulp-angular-embed-templates/issues/13

Comment: Any chance you could extend your answer for webpack users ?

Comment: @Ced There's an official guide https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Comment: @Martin I've read that unfortunately that is not what I'm looking for. In the page you linked what they use is a loader that puts the css inline in the html page. What I'm looking for is how can I publish a component with its css on npm using webpack. For that I need one js file. I just don't get  how to load the css