# how to bundle feature modules and load them on demand in angular2 app

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular2-routing, systemjs, systemjs-builder

I am working on an angular2 application, where I want to use lazy loading of feature modules. Separating modules as feature modules and loading them on demand works fine in dev mode, but how do I bundle feature modules separately(using systemjs) and load them in production?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give any advice from such short description. SystemJS has a tool called SystemJS Builder that can bundle multiple SystemJS modules into a single bundle (a single file with multiple modules).

Then SystemJS has an option [`bundle` option](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#bundle) to load bundles made by SystemJS Builder.

See a similar question with example of SystemJS Builder: [Build Angular2 HTML and TypeScript to a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867660/build-angular2-html-and-typescript-to-a-single-file/35868706#35868706)

Comment: My question is about creating multiple bundles for each feature module for example, two separate bundles for hero and crisis app in tour of heroes app. 

I am using systemjs builder and I am able to create bundles (revisioned) using bundle arithmetic, now the question is that how to provide system js bundle configuration so that I can load these bundles on demand.