# How to bundle Angular 2 app with systemjs and systemjs-builder?

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp, systemjs, systemjs-builder

I'm developing an app and I need to increase the angular 2 performance loading all the scripts. The problem is this error:

[image]

I'm using gulp + systemjs + systemjs-builder. Here is my files:

**[gulpfile]**

```
gulp.task('bundle', function () {
    var builder = new SystemBuilder('./', './wwwroot/lib/js/systemjs.config.js');
    return builder.buildStatic('wwwroot/lib/spa/main.js', 'wwwroot/lib/js/bundle.min.js', {
        minify: true,
        mangle: true,
        rollup: true,
        runtime: false
    });
});
```

**[systemjs.config]**

```
var config = {
        //use typescript for compilation
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        transpilerRuntime: false,
        //typescript compiler options
        typescriptOptions: {
            emitDecoratorMetadata: true
        },
        map: map,
        packages: packages,
        defaultJSExtensions: true
    };
```

As you can see it is added **.js** to transpiler as result of **defaultJSExtensions: true**. Do I need to do something different? (I really need this property equals to true, because I have a lot of paths without **.js**).

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867660/build-angular2-html-and-typescript-to-a-single-file/35868706#35868706

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer =) I tried the second point with the paths thing and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by adding

```
var map = {'typescript': 'node_modules/typescript/lib', ...}
```

and

```
var packages = {'typescript': { main: "typescript.js", ... }}
```

to config in systemjs file:

```
var config = {
        //use typescript for compilation
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        //typescript compiler options
        typescriptOptions: {
            emitDecoratorMetadata: true
        },
        map: map,
        packages: packages,
        defaultJSExtensions: true
    };
System.config(config);
```

This way systemjs-builder has no problem to find the transpiler path. 
Following the martin url ([Build Angular2 HTML and TypeScript to a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867660/build-angular2-html-and-typescript-to-a-single-file/35868706#35868706)) and searching about topic 3 I found this thing https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/production-workflows.md
to help on bundle loading. =)