# How do I actually deploy an Angular 2 + Typescript + systemjs app?

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

There's a quickstarter tutorial over at angular.io which uses typescript & systemjs.
Now that I've got that miniapp running, how would I go about creating something deployable? I couldn't find any info about it whatsoever.

Do I need any extra tools, any additional settings in System.config?

(I know that I could use webpack & create a single bundle.js, but I'd like to use systemjs as it is used in the tutorial)

Could someone share their build process with this setup (Angular 2, TypeScript, systemjs)

Comment: Here is my recipe for building an ng2 app for deployment using JSPM: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34616199/3532945

Comment: simple answer 
ng build -prod
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38421680/5079380

Answer (score 65):

The key thing to understand at this level is that using the following configuration, you can't concat compiled JS files directly.

At the TypeScript compiler configuration:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

In the HTML

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    app: {
      defaultExtension: 'js',
      format: 'register'
    }
  }
});
```

As a matter of fact, these JS files will contain anonymous modules. An anonymous module is a JS file that uses `System.register` but without the module name as first parameter. This is what the typescript compiler generates by default when systemjs is configured as module manager.

So to have all your modules into a single JS file, you need to leverage the `outFile` property within your TypeScript compiler configuration.

You can use the following inside gulp to do that:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');

var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
  typescript: require('typescript'),
  outFile: 'app.js'
});

gulp.task('tscompile', function () {
  var tsResult = gulp.src('./app/**/*.ts')
                     .pipe(ts(tsProject));

  return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

This could be combined with some other processing:

- to uglify things the compiled TypeScript files
- to create an `app.js` file
- to create a `vendor.js` file for third-party libraries
- to create a `boot.js` file to import the module that bootstrap the application. This file must be included at the end of the page (when all the page is loaded).
- to update the `index.html` to take into account these two files

The following dependencies are used in the gulp tasks:

- gulp-concat
- gulp-html-replace
- gulp-typescript
- gulp-uglify

The following is a sample so it could be adapted.

- Create `app.min.js` file

  ```
  gulp.task('app-bundle', function () {
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
      typescript: require('typescript'),
      outFile: 'app.js'
    });

    var tsResult = gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
                     .pipe(ts(tsProject));

    return tsResult.js.pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
                  .pipe(uglify())
                  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
  });
  ```
- Create `vendors.min.js` file

  ```
  gulp.task('vendor-bundle', function() {
    gulp.src([
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('vendors.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
  });
  ```
- Create `boot.min.js` file

  ```
  gulp.task('boot-bundle', function() {
    gulp.src('config.prod.js')
      .pipe(concat('boot.min.js'))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
   });
  ```

  The `config.prod.js` simply contains the following:

  ```
   System.import('boot')
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  ```
- Update the `index.html` file

  ```
  gulp.task('html', function() {
    gulp.src('index.html')
      .pipe(htmlreplace({
        'vendor': 'vendors.min.js',
        'app': 'app.min.js',
        'boot': 'boot.min.js'
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
  });
  ```

  The `index.html` looks like the following:

  ```
  <html>
    <head>
      <!-- Some CSS -->

      <!-- build:vendor -->
      <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
      <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
      <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
      <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
      <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
      <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
      <!-- endbuild -->

      <!-- build:app -->
      <script src="config.js"></script>
      <!-- endbuild -->
    </head>

    <body>
      <my-app>Loading...</my-app>

      <!-- build:boot -->
      <!-- endbuild -->
    </body>
  </html>
  ```

Notice that the `System.import('boot');` must be done at the end of the body to wait for all your app components to be registered from the `app.min.js` file.

I don't describe here the way to handle CSS and HTML minification.

Comment: can you create a github repo with an example please?

Comment: I followed your instructions and all looks fine with regards to gulp. However, when I run the app in the browser I get this console log error: "system.src.js:1625 Uncaught TypeError: Multiple anonymous System.register calls in the same module file." Any ideas what this means and how to fix it?

Comment: @AngularM: do you have the outFile parameter? This is the key for your error ;-)

Comment: I have it in my gulp file and tsconfig

Comment: Could you have a look at the github project I submitted? See my comment above. Do you see some differences with your code?

Comment: I have had a look at your repository but I dont no why that error occurs? I know i dont have the typings folder. not even sure what thats for?

Comment: I tried to npm run tsc your app in github and it doesnt work. I added an issue: https://github.com/templth/angular2-packaging/issues/1

Comment: Could you please update github repository to support angular 2 RC6.

Answer (score 28):

You can use angular2-cli build command

```
ng build -prod
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#bundling

> Builds created with the **-prod** flag via `ng build -prod` or `ng serve -prod` bundle all dependencies into a **single file**, and make use of **tree-shaking** techniques.

## Update

This answer was submitted when angular2 was in rc4

I had tried it again on angular-cli beta21 and  angular2 ^2.1.0 and it is working as expected

This answer requires initializing the app with angular-cli
you can use

```
ng new myApp
```

Or on an existing one

```
ng init
```

## Update 08/06/2018

For angular 6 the syntax is different.

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```

Check the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#build-with---prod)

Comment: This requires that your app is structured in angular-cli's opinionated structure.

Comment: @Amr ElAdawy FYI angular-cli moved to webpack. This question is related to SystemJS. ng build is not worked for me.

Comment: @ShahriarHasanSayeed Are you referring to the time I submitted the answer or the time you tried it?

Comment: @AmrElAdawy, can you add the versions for the modules where this actually works.  Angular2 has changed quite a bit since July.

Comment: @AmrElAdawy did you try it on a simple SystemJS based project like Angular 2 Tutorial? The ng build prints out the error requiring the project to be created with Angular 2 CLI. No idea why Angular2 ecosystem lacks this internal coherence, but Michael Pell is right - in general this method does not work.

Comment: @Michael I see your point and what Michael Pell is saying. I know that Angular2 5min quick start does not use the CLI to init the app. Which makes your comments valid. I will update the answer to show that it requires angular-cli initialization.

Comment: @AmrElAdawy, I am torn between following angular-seed template and generate something with angular-cli. The former uses its own big library of gulp tasks and system.config.ts. The later uses webpack behind the scenes and you don't have an access to the configuration (unless you hack the webpack template). The former seems professional and suitable for big projects developed by a team. The later seems faster up-ramp and more suited for a solo developer who is just learning the ropes

Comment: @Michael , Cann't help with that :) It is your choice. Both approaches are answered here. I personally, use the cli approach.

Comment: It is trivial to convert the Tour of Heroes tutorial to the cli version. Just generate a new project using cli and then copy the tutorial files over.

Comment: ng build create a dist folder in proj structure. But how to deploy this on a JBOSS/Weblogic server?

Comment: File this as a question and I will post the answer. it is like any static HTML files that go to the root folder.

Comment: ng init has been deprecated

Answer (score 12):

You can build an Angular 2 (2.0.0-rc.1) project in Typescript using SystemJS with [Gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) and [SystemJS-Builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder).

Below is a simplified version of how to build, bundle, and minify Tour of Heroes running 2.0.0-rc.1 ([full source](https://github.com/smmorneau/tour-of-heroes/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L63), [live example](https://tour-of-heroes-typescript.herokuapp.com/)).

**gulpfile.js**

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
var systemjsBuilder = require('systemjs-builder');

// Compile TypeScript app to JS
gulp.task('compile:ts', function () {
  return gulp
    .src([
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "typings/*.d.ts"
    ])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(typescript({
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "app",
        "target": "ES5"
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});

// Generate systemjs-based bundle (app/app.js)
gulp.task('bundle:app', function() {
  var builder = new systemjsBuilder('public', './system.config.js');
  return builder.buildStatic('app', 'app/app.js');
});

// Copy and bundle dependencies into one file (vendor/vendors.js)
// system.config.js can also bundled for convenience
gulp.task('bundle:vendor', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
        'node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.min.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
        'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      ])
        .pipe(concat('vendors.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor'));
});

// Copy dependencies loaded through SystemJS into dir from node_modules
gulp.task('copy:vendor', function () {
  gulp.src(['node_modules/rxjs/**/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/lib/js/rxjs'));

  gulp.src(['node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api/**/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/lib/js/angular2-in-memory-web-api'));
  
  return gulp.src(['node_modules/@angular/**/*'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/lib/js/@angular'));
});

gulp.task('vendor', ['bundle:vendor', 'copy:vendor']);
gulp.task('app', ['compile:ts', 'bundle:app']);

// Bundle dependencies and app into one file (app.bundle.js)
gulp.task('bundle', ['vendor', 'app'], function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'app/app.js',
        'vendor/vendors.js'
        ])
    .pipe(concat('app.bundle.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['bundle']);
```

**system.config.js**

```js
var map = {
  'app':                                'app',
  'rxjs':                               'vendor/rxjs',
  'zonejs':                             'vendor/zone.js',
  'reflect-metadata':                   'vendor/reflect-metadata',
  '@angular':                           'vendor/@angular'
};

var packages = {
  'app':                                { main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'rxjs':                               { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'zonejs':                             { main: 'zone', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'reflect-metadata':                   { main: 'Reflect', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};

var packageNames = [
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/router-deprecated',
  '@angular/testing',
  '@angular/upgrade',
];

packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
  packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

System.config({
  map: map,
  packages: packages
});
```

Comment: Could you please specify, how to run SystemJs and Gulp?

Comment: @JanDrozen In the same location as your gulpfile, you can run `gulp <taskname>` where "taskname" is the name of the task that calls the SystemJS builder, in my above example it is `bundle:app`. In that Gulp task you can use the 'systemjs-builder' npm module to specify your System config and outfile.

Comment: @ steely: Thanks! Works like a charm. Expect to the default target - the uglify() method is missing (or I am missing something). Can you please explain me this last unclear part?

Comment: @Steely would you please guide how to do it with newer version of angular2?

Comment: @Steely.can you provide a final link(on github) of latest angular2 build files which are required to run angular2 quickstart-app?

Comment: @micronyks Here is the latest quickstart app that I have deploying and building on Heroku: https://github.com/smmorneau/tour-of-heroes

Answer (score 1):

Here's my MEA2N boilerplate for Angular 2: https://github.com/simonxca/mean2-boilerplate

It's a simple boilerplate that uses `tsc` to put things together. (Actually uses [grunt-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ts), which at its core is just the `tsc` command.) No Wekpack, etc. necessary.

Whether or not you use grunt, the idea is:

- write your app in a folder called `ts/` (example: `public/ts/`)
- use `tsc` to mirror the directory structure of your `ts/` folder into a `js/` folder and just reference files in the `js/` folder in your `index.html`.

To get **grunt-ts** to work (there should be an equivalent command for plain tsc, Gulp, etc.) , you have a property in your `tsconfig.json` called `"outDir": "../js"`, and reference it in your `gruntfile.js` with:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  ts: {
    source: {tsconfig: 'app/ts/tsconfig.json'}
  },
  ...
});
```

Then run `grunt ts`, which will take your app in `public/ts/` and mirror it to `public/js/`.

There. Super easy to understand. Not the best approach, but a good one to get started.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I have found to bundle angular rc1 for systemJs is to use `gulp` and `systemjs-builder`:

```
gulp.task('bundle', function () {
    var path = require('path');
    var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');

    var builder = new Builder('/node_modules');

    return builder.bundle([
        '@angular/**/*.js'
        ], 
        'wwwroot/bundle.js', 
        { minify: false, sourceMaps: false })
        .then(function () {
            console.log('Build complete');
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Build error');
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

As pointed out in the comments, systemJs currently has issues when bundling components using `moduleId: module.id`

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6131

The current recommendation (angular 2 rc1) seems to be to use explicit paths i.e. `moduleId: '/app/path/'`

Comment: This seems promising but it fails when I use relative paths to external templates in the `@Component` decorator.  `bundle.js` tries to resolve paths as absolute even though they're relative, causing 404 errors (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497635/systemjs-builder-angular-2-component-relative-paths-cause-404-errors).  How have you dealt with that?

Comment: are you setting `moduleId` to the relative path?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  I have `moduleId: module.id` in `@Component`

Comment: That has the same drawbacks as putting down the full path under `templateUrl` and defeats the purpose of having `moduleId` in the first place. I'm trying to use relative paths as recommended (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html)

Comment: you may have more luck by explicitly setting the path yourself e.g. `moduleId: '/app/components/home/'`

Comment: funny, the server posted my last reply above before your comment

Comment: **Note**: This will not work for Angular2 2.2.x.  It can't even find node_modules/@angular/**/*.js files.  And how does this find my app?

Answer (score 0):

Under Angular.io website, under Advanced/Deployment section, it is recommended that the simplest way to deploy is 'to copy the development environment to the server'.

1. go through the section under: Simplest deployment possible. The final project files are shown inside the code section. Note that it already sets up the code to load npm package files from the web (in stead of from the local npm_modules folder).
2. make sure it is running on your local computer (npm start). Then under the project folder, copy everything under '/src' sub-folder to the S3 bucket you've set up. You can use drag-and-drop to copy, during that process, you get the option to select the permission setting for the files, make sure to make them 'readable' to 'everyone'.
3. under bucket 'Properties' tab, look for 'Static website hosting' panel, check on 'Use this bucket to host website' option, and specify 'index.html' to both Index document and Error document.
4. click on the static website Endpoint, your project well be running!