# Angular2 in production

Tags: angular, environment

I just started digging into Angular2. Looks promising at this point.
One this I could not find is production deployment best practices or guides (if any). 
Of course, I could run npm in production and serve the thing through light server, but isn't is best to compile everything for deployment? I am aware that I can precompile everything (even into a single file), but do I need to maintain different entry file for that? (by the way, I tried it and it does not work out of the box).

Any advice?

Comment: In this case, it is a duplicate. delete this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in fact, you can leverage same practices (concat, uglify, html-replace) than for an Angular1 application except for the TypeScript part. Note that I can't unfortunately make work useref in this context...

You need to leverage the TypeScript compiler and its `outFile` property to compile all your TypeScript files to JavaScript and into a single file that can be uglify then.

See this question for more details:

- [How do I actually deploy an Angular 2 + Typescript + systemjs app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285064/how-do-i-actually-deploy-an-angular-2-typescript-systemjs-app/36315060)

Comment: Is using gult my only option?

Comment: The other options are npm itself and grunt but gulp is really flexible and convenient for such tasks ;-)