# Pass environment variables to an Angular2 app?

Tags: angular, environment

I need to pass the backend url to my Angular2 app, since production and dev servers are hosted on different locations.

I know I could store such things in an external config.json and load upon startup. This, however, seems like unnecessary extra call to server before the app can get started.

Alternatively, what I do now is I do create a single global variable, which I inject in gulp depending on build. My app isn't a lib that needs to be reusable I don't believe I should hit *unexpected* global name clashes. But it's not a good practice.

I wonder if there's a third, better solution?

Comment: IMO, you're over-optimizing. I'll take a single "unnecessary" get in order to implement a well-understood pattern (like loading such things from a config file) every time.

Comment: You're possibly right, especially when Angular 2 hits production and the production builds and minification starts working really good. Thanks.

Comment: If using angular-cli, easy solution to this described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424199/angular-2-testing-process-env

Comment: If you have to build once and deploy the same build artifact multiple times, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43980985/2540679

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would see two ways to do that:

- Leverage a JSON configuration in a file. This file would be loaded before boostrapping the application:

  ```
  var app = platform(BROWSER_PROVIDERS)
     .application([BROWSER_APP_PROVIDERS, appProviders]);

  var http = app.injector.get(Http);
  http.get('config.json').subscribe((config) => {
    return app.bootstrap(AppComponent, [
      provide('config', { useValue: config })
    ]);
  }).toPromise();
  ```

  Here is a corresponding plunkr describing the global approach: https://plnkr.co/edit/ooMNzEw2ptWrumwAX5zP?p=preview.
- Leverage a configuration module:

  ```
  export const CONFIG = {
    (...)
  };
  ```

  that will be imported and included in providers when bootstrapping the application:

  ```
    import {CONFIG} from './config';

    bootstrap(AppComponent, [
      provide('config', { useValue: CONFIG })
    ]);
  ```

With the two approaches, configuration can be defined for each environment when packaging the application.

This question could also give you hints about how to package an Angular2 application:

- [How do I actually deploy an Angular 2 + Typescript + systemjs app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285064/how-do-i-actually-deploy-an-angular-2-typescript-systemjs-app/36315060)

Comment: Well, the first answer I've described already. For the third one, how would you set the `CONFIG` variables based on the environment I'm building for?

Answer (score 17):

Just put variables inside the environment object.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api'
};
```

After that, you could import and use it. Angular Cli will swap files automatically.

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

P.S. Variables are available in environment object.

```
this.url = environment.url
```

Comment: this works very well , from within any component/service/pipe , however 
how to access those variables from the main app.js ?
console.log(process.env.anotherVariable) is undefined ...

Comment: when I tried it I get the error 'cannot find name process'

Comment: Anyway a simpler solution with angular-cli is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424199/angular-2-testing-process-env

Answer (score 6):

I have been struggling with the above for a while too. And even though Thierry's answer is very good, but I somehow find it too complicated for simply having env vars, so I thought I present my thoughts too.

1) I first created an interface describing my env vars `app.settings.ts`:

```
export interface IEnvVars {
    ENV: string;
    API_URL: string;
}

export class AppSettings {
    public static env_vars: IEnvVars;
}
```

2) [I added the JavaScript fetch API type definitions to my .d.ts file.](https://github.com/ryan-codingintrigue/typescript-fetch) (Not absolutely needed if you don't mind having fetch as unresolved, but I did mind it, so added the types)

3) So now in my `main.ts` I can make a call to the endpoint that returns the environment variables:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {AppSettings,IEnvVars} from "./configs/app.settings";
import {enableProdMode} from "angular2/core";

fetch('/env-vars', {method: 'get'}).then((response) => {
    response.json().then((env_vars:IEnvVars) => {
        AppSettings.env_vars = env_vars;
        if (AppSettings.env_vars.ENV != 'development') enableProdMode();
        bootstrap(AppComponent);
    });
});
```

So now I access my env vars in any service or component simply by:

```
import {AppSettings} from "../configs/app.settings";
```

so within a method etc. you could go like:

```
let customersURL = `${AppSettings.env_vars.API_URL}/customers`;
```

Please note that you may need polyfills for fetch API as Safari and IE still don't support this. ([Link to polyfill exampel](https://github.com/github/fetch))

Comment: Thanks, but the question was about how do you set the /env-vars endpoint. (Without having access to backend.) I'm going with gulp build step now.

Comment: @Zlatko `/env-vars` is an endpoint that contains your settings or could be just a pure json file `/env-vars.json` located within your porject.

Comment: There is an issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3540 that you might face using such approach so you need to use the work around https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3540#issuecomment-275853502 until angular-cle getitg it fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Not only the URL but there are some other parameters that need to be taken from environment variables.

Environment variables must be taken and written to `environment.ts` before *build*! because of some Javascript restrictions in accessing filesystem, environment, etc at runtime.

For this, first you need a module for writing environment variables and this module has to be executed with `ts-node` in your `build` script:

```
"scripts": {
  .....
  "config": "ts-node set-env.ts",
  "build": "npm run config && ng build",
  ....
},
```

and your `set-env.ts` file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const targetPath = './src/environments/environment.ts';
const colors = require('colors');
require('dotenv').load();
const envConfigFile = `export const environment = {
  ENV_VAR_1: '${process.env.var_1}',
  ENV_VAR_n: '${process.env.var_n}',
};`;
console.log(colors.magenta('The content of `environment.ts` will be: \n'));
console.log(colors.grey(envConfigFile));
fs.writeFile(targetPath, envConfigFile, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(colors.magenta(`environment.ts file is created`));
  }
});
```

and of course you have to add `ts-node` and `dotenv` to your dependencies.

and you can easily access variables of environemnt.ts like:

```
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
....
var envVar1 = environment.ENV_VAR_1;
```

---

Node 12^, Angular 10^, and I didn't check this with older Node/Angular/Typescrip versions

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be useful to you.
[Passing asp.net server parameters to Angular 2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337185/passing-asp-net-server-parameters-to-angular-2-app)

This way you can inject any value from html page (which can get value from the server, like current environment variable)

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this using the following approach:

1. Created `ts` files for each environment.
2. Modified `package.json` and added a new entry for every environment in scripts section.

**for eg:-**

> "start:local": "copy \"config/config.local.ts\" \"constants/global.constants.ts\" && npm run start"

3. Import `global.constants` into your app.
4. You can start your HTTP server using : `npm run start:local`

Comment: Do you have any "devDependencies" to make that copy command work? I get an error, `The system cannot find the file specified. 0 file(s) copied.` I thought it was a pathing issue but In Visual Studio Code, I'm allowed to Ctrl+click the file and it is indeed there.

Answer (score -1):

In different **environments**, the value of `location.host` will be different.

Use this as the *key* and load the values from the corresponding `json` having all the URLs.

The relevant code may look like this:

```
let env = location.host;
if (env === 'prod.example.com') {
  config = 'ProdConfig.json';
} else if (env === 'test.example.com') {
  config = 'TestConfig.json';
} else if (env === 'localhost') {
  config = 'DevConfig.json';
}
```

Comment: Not in my case. Let's say I am running my local, dev env. And I have locally the API. But a colleague doesn't have the backend installed locally (databases, all the setup, he doesn't need it) - he'll point the backend-url to our sandbox API. That's why I don't want to resolve this from the app itself, but rather at build time.

Answer (score -3):

## Environment.ts

### How to use it

you have a builtin system for that in Angular2+.
you have  `environement.ts` files for every environement you handle(you can define as much as you need).
Wehenever you need to access them, you import it like this

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment.ts'
```

and in the code you access your variable

```
environement.varName
```

### How to configure custom environement.ts

in your angular.json file, you can create as many environement as you want, here is an example

```
"build": 
{ "configurations": 
{ 
"production": { "fileReplacements": [ { "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts", "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts" } ], }, 

"qa": { "fileReplacements": [ { "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts", "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts" } ] }, 

"staging": { "fileReplacements": [ { "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts", "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts" } ] } } }
```

when building your application you need to mention the name of the environement you build for.
foe example here I made a build for **qa** environement.

```
ng build --configuration qa
```

once done, your **dist** output folder should contain build output with **qa** configuration