# Access global variable in angular2

Tags: angular

Main.ts

```
 import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
 import { AppModule } from './app.module';
 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.module.ts

```
 import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent     }  from './app.component';
 //service
import { DataService }  from './shared/data.service';
@NgModule({
   imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule],
   declarations: [ AppComponent   ],                
   providers:    [ DataService], 
   bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
  })
 export class AppModule {}
```

starting point

```
  <script>
    var temp = "Prafulla";
    System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
 </script>
```

I want `to use temp variable inside angular2`   I tried using this link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662794/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angular2-component) but not work I donot understand how and where to write main function my `app.module.ts`

how to do it?

Comment: What is error you are getting?

Comment: TypeError: AppModule.main is not a function

Comment: You have to add the provider in the `app.module.ts`

Comment: System.import('app').then(function (AppModule) { AppModule.main(temp); }).catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });

Comment: can you give me hint because I tried like creating main method in app.module.ts  but not work

Comment: @Dinistro  please give answer I tried but provide showing error

Comment: refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37384405/5292301) but same it shows old syntax how to implement in new  main.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add your value in the providers of the AppModule:

```ts
@NgModule({
   imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule],
   declarations: [ AppComponent ],                
   providers: [
                 DataService,
                 {provide: 'rootVar', useValue: rootVar}
              ], 
   bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
  })
 export class AppModule {}
```

Now you should be able to access the value in your components and services:

```ts
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(@Inject('rootVar') rootVar) {}
}
```