# how to set config or properties file for different environments in Angular?

Tags: angular, deployment, build, properties, config

Angular 5.2.9 : I have to change some api keys according to different environments (pre prod, prod etc). But right now I have to change the keys in my appSettings class and build it every time before deploying on each env. Is the a way to keep the api keys inside some config or properties file so that I can keep it on each env and deploy same built code everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I use two different ways of configuring my Angular applications. The first one is to render the Angular `index.html` page on server side. You can use any language on backend to render an HTML page that contains :

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>...</title>
  <base href="/angular-app-context/">
  <script>
  var CONFIG = {
    BACKEND_URL : "http://10.0.0.1:9000/backend-context/",
    AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES : "fr,de,it".split(",")
    // here you can configure whatever you want with server-side properties
  };
  </script>
  <link href="styles.16fc164c6ad7cb#######.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.f499ecf4e7218#######.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- other Angular files -->
```

Please note that Angular files generated by the compilation are named with a checksum in the name. You will need somehow to inject these names dynamically into your `index.html` template. In my case, I'm doing this using Gradle, which does compile the Angular application, retrieve the names of the generated files from the `dist` folder, then inject them into an `index.html` template file of a Tomcat very simple WAR application (details are out of the scope of your question).

These `CONFIG` properties can be accessed from your Angular code. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662794/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angular2-component) showing how. My advice is to use this for minimal configuration only (typically backend URL's).

A second way of configuring your application is to load information from the backend using HTTP at startup. Just pack them as JSON and access them through a regular `HttpClient` call. You can use the `BACKEND_URL` from my first suggestion to help if you have backends having very different URL's.