# Getting value from inline script defined value in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm have a generated value on the page (pageId) which is added inline in a script tag.

```
<script>
var pageId = @Model.Id
</script>
```

I then want to use this value in some Typescript (Angular App). Obviously I get an error it's not defined. Do can I define it so it's assumed it's present on the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access global js variable in angular2 component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662794/how-to-access-global-js-variable-in-angular2-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a global variable. Angular best practice for accessing global variables is to provide them through dependency injection like you would a service.

This has [already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37662884/1966301) before, if it helps please mark Thierry Templier's answer as useful.