# Passing server parameters to ngModule after RC5 upgrade

Tags: angular

I'm trying again to pass parameters to my application. Since RC5, I have to use ngModule. (this solution: [Passing asp.net server parameters to Angular 2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337185/passing-asp-net-server-parameters-to-angular-2-app) no longer works since RC5)

How to pass parameters to ngModule?

Here's a plunker to illustrate problem: 
**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fJm51MoeKfcCnl6b5Ffn?p=preview)**

index.html:

```
<script>
  System.import('app').then(module =>   module.main('This is RIGHT'),
                console.error.bind(console)
            );
</script>
```

main.ts:

```
import { browserDynamicPlatform } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

export function main(test: string) {

  browserDynamicPlatform().bootstrapModule(AppModule, [{ providers: provide('Test', { useValue: test, }) }]);
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, provide }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }       from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    provide('Test', { useValue: 'This is WRONG' })
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: I'm also working on the same problem at this moment. Trying to figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update 2**

**Webpack** implementation you can find here
[Passing server parameters to ngModule with Angular 2 and webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938018/passing-server-parameters-to-ngmodule-with-angular-2-and-webpack/39941092#39941092)

---

*Systemjs*

**Update 1:**

We can pass data in the `extraProviders` property of `browserDynamicPlatform` function:

**main.ts**

```
export function main(test: string) {
  browserDynamicPlatform([{provide: 'Test', useValue: test }])
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

This way the `createAppModule` function in *app.module.ts* is redundant.

**[Plunker 2.0 Final](http://plnkr.co/edit/eg1Un1UhduBFGxksRf9P?p=preview)**

---

**Previous version**

For RC.5 you can add a method (i.e. `createAppModule`) in `app.module.ts` like this:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

export function createAppModule(test) {
  @NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    providers: [
      { provide: 'Test', useValue: test },
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  class AppModule { }

  return AppModule;
}
```

This way your main module would be like this:

**main.ts**

```
import { browserDynamicPlatform } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { createAppModule } from './app.module';

export function main(test: string) {
  browserDynamicPlatform().bootstrapModule(createAppModule(test));
}
```

And your starting point remains the same:

**index.html**

```
<script>
  System.import('app')
    .then(module => module.main('This is RIGHT'),
       console.error.bind(console)
    );
</script>
```

Here is **[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ojaneZSSihUvkLmrpNkh?p=preview)**

Comment: nice. didn't know we could put attributes inside a function.

Comment: Great solution. Is it possible to implement this in production when i use a systemjs builder and it produces one bundled file which i include in the index.html? System.import does not work anymore with this bundled file. I have messed up with systemjs config file for a day without success.

Comment: I use "systemjs builder" with a bundle and this solution didn't cause any issues for me.

Comment: Is the systemjs-webpack-plugin what you had used?
https://github.com/guybedford/systemjs-webpack-plugin

Comment: @yurzui how do I send dynamic content to index.html as I mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920091/aspnet-core-new-angular-5-cli-template

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the below work around that works in angular2 2.0.1

[Loading server side settings before loading components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40164650/3094053)

Guard your route with a CanActivate class using a Promise which loads the config settings should also work.

Use the appSettings.service with  a function just like the one returning a promise

```
getAppSettings(): Promise<any> {
        var observable = this.http.get(this.ApiUrl, { headers: this.headers })
            .map((response: Response) => {
                var res = response.json();
                return res;
            });

        observable.subscribe(config => {
        this.config= config;
        console.log(this.config)
        });
        return observable.toPromise();  
    }
```

And the CanActivate guard as below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AppSettingsService } from './appsettings.service';

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateViaAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

//router: Router
    constructor(private appSettingsService: AppSettingsService)
    {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
               return this.appSettingsService.getAppSettings().then(() => { 
    return true });
   }
}
```

This will ensure that your settings are available when the corresponding components are constructed. (using the APP_INITIALIZER did not restrict the constructor being called, so I had to use this technic, Also please make sure, you dont export all the components in the exports:[] in the module)

To guard the routes and ensure settings are loaded before the constructors are called, please use the usual canActivate option in the path for the route definition

```
 path: 'abc',
 component: AbcComponent,
 canActivate: [CanActivateViaAuthGuard]
```

The initialization of appsettings should happen before the constructor for AbcComponent is called, this is tested and works in Angular 2.0.1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14049369)

Comment: I dont mind adding more details, but my intention was not to have duplicate answers

Comment: I didn't want to pass server params through http. The first answer with 11+ votes answered me perfectly.