# Angular 2 Input binding does not work

Tags: angular

index.html:

```
  <app [myname]="some_name"></app>
```

app.component.ts:

```
  import {Component, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: '<span>{{myname}}</span>'
  })

  export class CupBuyComponent {
      @Input() myname: String;

      constructor(){
          console.log(this.myname);
      }
  }
```

JS console says undefined. How can I get variables from .html file to send it to component?

Comment: Because you haven't defined value for `myname`, so it would be undefined? As you mentioned in `title`, I don't see input in your question

Comment: Just don't do it on the root component (`AppComponent`).

Comment: Read my edited comment below, I explained why your code won't work even with solution @yurzui and I provided.

Answer (score 14):

**Update**

> The reason why this is not working is that your index.html in which
>   you place the  is not an angular
>   component. Because of this, Angular won't compile this element. And
>   Angular does not read attribute values during runtime, only during
>   compile time, as otherwise we would get a performance hit.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858#issuecomment-151326461

This will do what you want:

**index.html**

```typescript
<app myname="some_name"></app>
```

**Root component**

```typescript
export class CupBuyComponent {
  @Input() myname: String;

  constructor(elm: ElementRef){
    this.myname = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('myname');
  }
}
```

Also if you want pass data as object you can take a look at this question

- [Passing server parameters to ngModule after RC5 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948463/passing-server-parameters-to-ngmodule-after-rc5-upgrade)

---

**Original**

If you want to pass data as text then it should be

```
<app [myname]="'some_name'"></app>
```

or

```
<app myname="some_name"></app>
```

Comment: all the same undefined

Answer (score 2):

**IMPORTANT**

> I explained below what's wrong with your binding, but even if you use the code I provided it won't work because you are trying to pass an input to the component you are bootstraping (root component), which is not possible.

If you want to pass string `some_name` to `myname` input variable, you should to it without `[]`:

```
<app myname="some_name"></app>
```

If you do it with `[]` like you did, it looks for variable named `some_name` in your component which you don't have and that's why you get `undefined` in your console.

Answer (score 1):

Its accessible in and after this event:

`ngOnInit() { ... here ... }`

and as the others already mentioned.. if you are using the `[myname]="variable or expression()"` syntax, inside the "" need to be a variable or an expression of your component..

If you are using this syntax `myname="anyStringHere"` you can paste only a string there..