# angular2 reading root component custom attribute value

Tags: angular

I am trying to read the following in the root component of an angular app

```
 <app-root [something]="'sometingvalue'">Loading...</app-root>
```

I have the angular component the following way

```
export class AppComponent {
    something: string = 'abcd';
    title: string = 'app works!';
    elm: ElementRef;


    constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
        this.elm = elm;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.something = this.elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('something');
    }
}
```

However I always get null on the ngOnInit even, how do I read this value.  I cannot use @input since this is the root component.

Comment: Have you tried `<app-root something="sometingvalue">`?

Comment: This won't work because then it tries to evaluate the expression inside the component

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614451/angular-2-input-binding-does-not-work/39614592#39614592

Answer (score 2):

Seems like its only possible to pass strings into those attributes!

See my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ThPAdFz2laP778JuEYb7?p=preview

For your info:

```html
<p [attribute-name]="expression-here"></p>
<p attribute-name="string-here"></p>
```

As you like to store a string, use the NON-expression way!

Comment: Thanks for this, the second one worked

<p attribute-name="string-here"></p>