# Angular 2 @input gives me undefined in console

Tags: angular, angular2-components

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, as I could not found any solutions elsewhere in web, so am posting this in StackOverflow

I have referred the duplicated question solutions in StackOverflow, I could not get any solutions for my question, as the solutions available in Stackoverflow are using two components, but am using single component.

**My Problem**

Am creating an angular 2 components, in which am having a @input to get the value of the selector attribute, if I do console.log of the @input am getting undefined as value

**Component**

```
import { Component,Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: ' <p>{{urlinput}}</p>'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
   @Input() urlinput;  
    ngOnInit() {console.log('value: ' + this.urlinput);}
}
```

**index.Html**

```
<app-root [urlinput]="hello">Loading...</app-root>
```

Please do correct the code if any this wrong, Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614451/angular-2-input-binding-does-not-work

Comment: @yurzui nope tried that also not working

Comment: Check out this https://plnkr.co/edit/UccAeE4sqoXPc7FHWWGd?p=preview It's the same as i mentioned above

Comment: if you'd just like to give the value of "hello" to your property `urlinput` while still using `@Input`, try changing your html to `<app-root [urlinput]="'hello'">Loading...</app-root>` and define a type for `urlinput` such as `@Input urlinput:string;`

Comment: @Drew13 i guess it won't work. He's trying to use `@Input` on non-angular element

Comment: @yurzui working fine in your plunkr link, but not in my local

Comment: Can you share your project on github?

Comment: yeah will do that, now I got working inside ngAfterViewInit but not inside the jquery  $(document).ready(function() {}