# @Input is not working Angular 2

Tags: angular

I 'm having a problem setting an Input property. What I'm trying to do is pass a value from app.component.ts called **passBool** and set the *property* of the nextComponent called **receivedBool**.

Here are my codes:

**app.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <nextComponent [receivedBool]="passBool"></nextComponent>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {

  //Variables
  passBool: Boolean = true;

  constructor(){
    console.log('The boolean value we are trying to pass is: ' + this.passBool)
  }

}
```

**nextComponent.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nextComponent',
  template: `<i> </i> `
})

export class NextComponent {

    @Input() receivedBool: Boolean = false;

    constructor () {
        console.log('The boolen value  we are receiving here is: ' + this.receivedBool)
    }

}
```

**Console log results are:**

`The boolean value we are trying to pass is: true` - app.component.ts

`The boolean value  we are receiving here is: false` - nextComponent.component.ts

I hope you could enlighten me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inputs are not yet available when the constructor is executed.

Use `ngOnInit()` instead:

```ts
export class NextComponent {
    @Input() receivedBool: Boolean = false;

    ngOnInit () {
        console.log('The boolen value  we are receiving here is: ' + this.receivedBool)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me figured the rest out!

Comment: The angular does not read attribute value during runtime only during compiling time, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614451/angular-2-input-binding-does-not-work/39614592#39614592

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer When you call the component initially when it's compiling it does not have value until runtime, in a interval you have empty value, according to the explanation.

Comment: You don't call a component when it's compiling. Compiling is before the browser loads the component.