# Angular 2 get config from server before bootstrap

Tags: angular

I need to get configuration from server before the application bootstraps. I was able to do that using this in providers in my main ngModule:

```
{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (links: Links) => () => links.init(),
    deps: [Links, Http],
    multi: true
}
```

Links service:

```
init(): Promise<any> {
    var observable = this.http.get('someUrl').map(res => res.json());
    observable.subscribe(res => {
        this.config = res;
    });
    return observable.toPromise();
}
```

This code gets executed before the application bootstraps, but the response from server is not present until after my app asks for Links.config. How do I force the app to not bootstrap until after the Promise gets resolved? I tried promise.resolve(), but it didn't help.

The way I used providers I thought I forced the app to use the same instance of Links and also I thought the data would be already present there. What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my code I am doing exactly same and it's working only difference is that I am converting the request to Promise before mapping.

```
public load(): Promise<void> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let url = this.urls.settings;

    return this.http.get(url, { headers }).toPromise().
        then(configs => {
            this.startupSettings = configs.json();
        }).catch(err => {
            log(err);
        });
}
```

...............................

```
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (config: StartupConfigurationService) => () => config.load(),
        deps: [StartupConfigurationService],
        multi: true
    }
```

I don't sure it will make sense but try may be it will solve

Comment: Brilliant, I had an error in resolving the promise, your way works. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

As suggested at [#37611549](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/40818182#40818182) and [#35215112](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215112/pass-page-global-variables-into-angular2-app-for-use-with-services/40818248#40818248), the [@ngx-config/core](https://github.com/nglibs/config) utility can be helpful to get your config from server during the app initialization.

You can achieve similar results by fetching data within SystemJS imports. However, I don't suggest such an approach - because it will create a risk that your config values won't be statically analyzable during AoT compilation.

Comment: Just linking to your own library is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/200235)

Comment: Thanks @Ferrybig. Of course I want to provide more detailed, in-depth code instructions. However, when I answer for the same problem on multiple threads, the system identifies it as a duplicate.

Comment: I've searched for hours about how to best provide a server-side config to the application. This answer is by far the most painless way to do it and it's very well documented. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the work around that I have used here

[Loading server side settings angular2 2.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40164650/3094053)

In short guard your route with a CanActivate class using a Promise which loads the config settings should also work.

Ensures that your settings are available when the corresponding components are constructed. (using the APP_INITIALIZER did not restrict the constructor being called, so I had to use this technic, Also please make sure, you dont export all the components in the exports:[] in the module)