# How to register a provider in Angular 2 with runtime data?

Tags: angular

In Beta I could do this:

```
export class AppBootstrapper {
  constructor(mySettings: AppSettings) {
    bootstrap(App, 
      [
        provide(AppSettings, {
          useFactory: () => mySettings
        })
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Whereby 'mySettings' is runtime data from the server.

How can I do this in the latest RC?

```
export class AppBootstrapper {
  constructor(mySettings: AppSettings) {
    platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  }
}
```

I can get it into Bootstrap, but not into app.module.ts

```
providers: [
  { provide: AppSettings, useFactory: => new AppSettings(??) }
]
```

,

Comment: You can try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39454713/2587435)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
export class AppBootstrapper {
  constructor(mySettings: AppSettings) {
    browserDynamicPlatform({ provide: AppSettings, useFactory: () => mySettings })
       .bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  }
}
```

Or just add some method `main` in your `app.module.ts` file that will return your `AppModule` and call this method like

```
platform.bootstrapModule(main(settings));
```

See also:

- [Passing server parameters to ngModule after RC5 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948463/passing-server-parameters-to-ngmodule-after-rc5-upgrade)