# Passing server parameters to ngModule with Angular 2 and webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to pass parameters to my application. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948463/passing-server-parameters-to-ngmodule-after-rc5-upgrade) which seems to have worked for people. The problem is I am using angular-cli to set up/build and ever since ~beta.14 it uses webpack instead of SystemJS.

My main.ts looks like this:

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export function main(appLocalized: any) {
  platformBrowserDynamic([{provide: 'AppLocalized', useValue: appLocalized }])
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

but I'm not sure how to access this function from index.html.

My dist/index.html looks like this:

```
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
```

My question is, how do I call the function to pass my data in, like is done in the other post:

```
<script>
  System.import('app').then(module =>   module.main('This is RIGHT'),
                console.error.bind(console)
            );
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With webpack you can achive it by using [output.library](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library) option within your `webpack.config.js`

**Step 1**

To configure it you need to change your config like:

```
output: {
  ...
  library: '[name]'
},
```

where `name` will be replaced with names of your entry's points.

This way your module will expose to global scope (window). For the `main` entry it might look as shown below:

[image]

**Step 2**

Entry **main.js**

```
export function run(appLocalized: any) {
  platformBrowserDynamic([{provide: 'AppLocalized', useValue: appLocalized }])
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

***Note***: `export` is necessarily

**Step 3**

Use it in your

**index.html**

```
// after all your bundles files
<script>
  main.run('Passing server parameters to ngModule with Angular 2 and webpack');
</script>
```

For HtmlWebpackPlugin it might look like:

```
<% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>
<script src="<%=htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %>"></script>
<% } %>

<script>
  main.run('Passing server parameters to ngModule with Angular 2 and webpack');
</script>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   template: 'src/index.html',
   inject: false <== don't forget this line
 }),
```

**Alternative way** is just define window property:

```
window["run"] = function(appLocalized: any) {
  platformBrowserDynamic([{provide: 'AppLocalized', useValue: appLocalized }])
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

then in your html

```
<script>
    run('Passing server parameters to ngModule with Angular 2 and webpack');
</script>
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks! I should have noted that with Angular-CLI there is no webpack.config.js right now because it uses a default setup. I tried hacking around in the webpack config files in the cli package but I'm in over my head there. Your alternative method worked great though.