# Angular2 - access ENV VARIABLES for deployment

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-services

I want to dynamically change **API_URL** in angular2 for deployment.

Like this

```
return this.http.get(process.env.API_URL +'contacts')
```

No Idea how to implement this in angular2.

Comment: Possible duplicate question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36528824/pass-environment-variables-to-an-angular2-app

Comment: Yup ur right, the same problem, i'll just check solutions provided