# Setup the environment variables of angular 2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am working with an angular 2 project with typescript and webpack. 
At the development time I should use local APIs or test APIs.
But when in production I should use the real APIs. So the API URL will changed.

APIs are used in many service files like product service etc.

I want to write all of my API URLs in a single file so that I can easily change the URLs when environment will changed.

How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe [use `location.host` as the key?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43649171/2404470)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a config file and store your config values there as an `object` key-value.

**config.ts:**

```
export var config = {
  title: "Hello World",
  "SecurityService":"http://localhost/SecurityAPI",
  "CacheService":"http://localhost/CacheServiceAPI"
}
```

**yourComponent.ts:**

```
import { config } from './config';

myTitle = config.title;
```

Full example: http://plnkr.co/edit/CGtxYJkcjYt2cEzrbL00?p=info

You can also do an http request to your external config file (json);

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/60E2qb9gOjvkEAeR5CtE?p=info

Answer (score 2):

You can create a TS class with static properties:

```
export class Environment {
   public static API_ENDPOINT = 'http://127.0.0.1:6666/api/';
}
```

Use it as following:

```
import { Environment } from './environment';

export class MyClass {
    apiEndpoint: string = Environment.API_ENDPOINT;
    ...
}
```

You can also create a `const` object:

```
export const environment = {
     API_ENDPOINT: 'http://127.0.0.1:6666/api/'
}
```

And use it like:

```
import { environment } from './environment';

export class MyClass {
    apiEndpoint: string = environment.API_ENDPOINT;
    ...
}
```