# Gulp - does anyone know how to cache bust a js file?

Tags: angular, gulp

Gulp - does anyone know how to cache bust a js file?

I'm using gulp, angular2 and html.

**Current gulp file with an attempt of cache busting:**

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
var htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');
var addsrc = require('gulp-add-src');
var cachebust = require('gulp-cache-bust');

// See this article: http://caveofcode.com/2016/03/gulp-tasks-for-minification-and-concatenation-of-dependencies-in-angularjs/

gulp.task('app-bundle', function () {
  var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
      typescript: require('typescript'),
      outFile: 'app.js'
  });

  var tsResult = gulp.src([
    'node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts',
    'app/**/*.ts'
  ])
    .pipe(ts(tsProject));

  return tsResult.js.pipe(addsrc.append('config-prod.js'))
                    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
                    .pipe(uglify())
                    .pipe(cachebust({type: 'timestamp'}))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));

});

gulp.task('vendor-bundle', function() {
    gulp.src([
            'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
            'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
            'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
            'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
            'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('vendors.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(cachebust({type: 'timestamp'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('html-replace',[ 'app-bundle', 'vendor-bundle' ], function() {
  gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(htmlreplace({
        'vendor': 'vendors.min.js',
        'app': 'app.min.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gulp-cache-bust` only appends a query string to asset references. It doesn't rename or change the assets themselves in any way.

That means applying `cachebust()` to your `.js` files makes no sense. You need to apply it to the HTML that references the `.js` files:

```
gulp.task('html-replace',[ 'app-bundle', 'vendor-bundle' ], function() {
  gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(htmlreplace({
      'vendor': 'vendors.min.js',
      'app': 'app.min.js'
    }))
    .pipe(cachebust({type: 'timestamp'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: it changed the file name in the index.html with t={{guid}}
But the filename in the folder didnt change. I'm guessing thats how it works?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. It appends a query string. Nothing else.

Comment: This made no changes to my `*.js` files renaming them in place (same directory) via `vinylPaths(del)` beforehand. What am I doing wrong?