# systemjs-builder: Angular 2 Component Relative Paths cause 404 errors

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, systemjs

This is a cross post to https://github.com/systemjs/builder/issues/611

I'm trying to bundle my Angular 2 rc 1 app with systemjs-builder 0.15.16 `buildStatic` method.  An angular component has a view as well as  one or more stylesheets external to the script. They are referred to within the `@Component` metadata in [one of two ways](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html)

Using absolute paths:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app/some.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['app/some.component.css']
})
```

Using the now recommended relative paths:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'some.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['some.component.css']
})
```

My app uses relative paths, and things have been working fine. Today I decided to use systemjs-builder's `buildStatic`.  The resulting file throws 404 errors whenever there is a relative path because the browser is fetching `localhost/some.component.html` instead of `localhost/app/some.component.html`.  Below is the relevant part of my **gulpfile.js**

```
var appDev = 'dev/';
var appProd = 'app/';
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
var tsProject = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json');
var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('build-ts', function () {
    return gulp.src(appDev + '**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(typescript(tsProject))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appProd));
});
gulp.task('bundle',['build-ts'], function() {

    var builder = new Builder('', './systemjs.config.js');

    return builder
        .buildStatic(appProd + '/main.js', appProd + '/bundle.js', { minify: false, sourceMaps: true})
        .then(function() {
            console.log('Build complete');
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Build error');
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

With relative paths, if I run just the `build-ts` gulp task and browse the "regular" way, things work. If I run the `bundle` gulp task and try to browse the app using the `bundle.js` file, the 404 errors occur wherever the app tries to load external templates and stylesheets. I've tried to be explicit about the relative nature of the paths by changing `templateUrl: 'some.component.html'` to `templateUrl: './some.component.html'` to no effect. Hard-coding absolute paths everywhere seems like a bad idea. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a couple of days I got [a helpful response](https://github.com/systemjs/builder/issues/611#issuecomment-222479225) from a systemjs member on github.

What did the trick: in the configuration object for systemjs-builder's `buildStatic` method, set `encodeNames` to `false`.  So the line...

```
.buildStatic(
    appProd + '/main.js', 
    appProd + '/bundle.js', 
    { minify: false, sourceMaps: true}
)
```

became...

```
.buildStatic(
    appProd + '/main.js', 
    appProd + '/bundle.js', 
    { minify: false, sourceMaps: true, encodeNames:false}
)
```

## Additional Info

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./app"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./dev/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to reproduce your solution. Even with encodeNames: false templates aren't loaded. Which url style did you end up using? What's your tsconfig module type?

Comment: I've  added my *tsconfig*.  If by url style you're referring to this (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles): I use the default (not the hash style).

Comment: Thanks. I had to change my config to commonjs as you have it. Using system modules and the corresponding `__moduleName` in lieu of module.id somehow breaks systemjs builds.

Comment: i was about to start pulling my hair out but then I read ur post