# Angular2: Rollupjs bundle with relative paths in component class

Tags: angular, gulp, rollupjs

To support i18n as explained [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html) I have to support AOT and therefore need to use relative `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` in my components and set `moduleId: module.id`.

This works perfect for my dev build which does not bundle and loads the files using systemjs (built using gulp)

1. compile typescript: `target: es5, module: commonjs'

In the production build I use rollup.js to tree-shake and bundle. Here I have to compliation steps since rollup needs es2015 modules and the browser (and to have module.id set in the components) needs common.js

1. compile typescript: `target: es5, module: es2015`
2. bundle with rollup.js: `format: iife`
3. compile typescript again: `target: es5, module: commonjs, allowJs: true`

Doing that I get the following error when running the app: **failed to load app.component.html**

Version info:

- angular: 2.2.1
- typescript: 2.0.10
- rollup: 0.36.3

Does anyone have an idea what is causing the problem?
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I have the exactly the same issue, have you found how to solve it?

Comment: @DicBrus Unfortunately not... I postponed that topic. But some time soon I will have to find a solution. I'm also thinking about moving over to Angular CLI / Webpack because I hope to not run into as many issues as I do with gulp / system.js

Comment: If I understood correctly that is the issue of SystemJS Builder
https://github.com/systemjs/builder/issues/737

Comment: looks like here is a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497635/systemjs-builder-angular-2-component-relative-paths-cause-404-errors