# Angular 2 how to import components from a CDN

Tags: angular

I'm wondering how you import components hosted somewhere else, like a CDN.

If I got a link to someone's CDN for example: `<script src="a-cdn-link.js"></script>` where a component named `MyComponent` resides, in my own component file, what would I use as the import path?

I know that you can use the framework itself if included via a CDN but I don't understand how they make it so that you fetch from the correct path. I haven't tried using the CDN to import angular2 so I'm not quite sure exactly how it works.

Would you have to declare a path via SystemJS or another similar service?

Could do with some enlightment on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can include JS files like this if they use `System.register('module-name', ...` to register explicitly a named module. JS files like that are generally generated from TypeScript ones leveraging the `outFile` option of the TypeScript compiler.

If your JS files correspond to anonymous System modules or CommonJS / AMD ones, you need to configure them within the SystemJS configuration.

The following question could give some additional hints:

- [How do I actually deploy an Angular 2 + Typescript + systemjs app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285064/how-do-i-actually-deploy-an-angular-2-typescript-systemjs-app/36315060)

Comment: So on the server side of things, you have to register the modules in SystemJS too? I'm not really familiar with SystemJS at all so what you just wrote doesn't make a whole lot of sense hehe.