# How should I prepare to release my Angular 4 + TypeScript +.Net MVC+ SystemJs app?

Tags: .net, angular

My .Net MVC project configured as described in https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015.
Can i do it without adding other tool like Gulp? Or the single way to do it was described in follow answer ( [How do I actually deploy an Angular 2 + Typescript + systemjs app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285064/how-do-i-actually-deploy-an-angular-2-typescript-systemjs-app) ).

Comment: It can depend on your project setup, if you are using angular-cli please take a look https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: i don't using angular cli in current project

Comment: Yes, the solution is on the link that you provide, you need to transpile/compile your source files and for that task you will need tools like Gulp (between others), using the CLI tool you save the pain of setting up that tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Download  VISUAL STUDIO COMMUNITY 2017 (or others this is free one )
or updated if you already have it then open new project. After the last update vs2017 you can choose MVC then angular for you UI development. Angular 2 in visual stdio typescript is default. All after this choices vs2017 will create all file you need in solution.