# How to deploy Angular app on github.io without using Angular CLI

Tags: angular, github, angular-cli, github-pages

Due to some reasons, I was not able to install Angular CLI on my system and I created a hello world app by following this URL https://blog.angularindepth.com/setting-up-angular-from-scratch-1f518c65d8ab.

All things working fine but now my next task it to upload it on github.io, there are numbers of articles or videos about it but all are using Angular CLI and as I mentioned earlier, my system don't have angular CLI then how can I deploy angular on github.io?

1) How I publish Angular App?
2) How or what things require to deploy on github.io

remember I am not using webPack.

Comment: using git doesn't have anything to do with Angular CLI does it? As far as i'm reading it, you can create a repo, clone it and push back to it...

Comment: Seems like the project you are using uses systemjs... so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285064/how-do-i-actually-deploy-an-angular-2-typescript-systemjs-app