# Multiple Angular2 Applications, Single Vendor Repository

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, subdomain

I would like to host various **Angular2** apps that utilize the same framework packages and `node_modules` from a root and subdomain:

1. `domain.com`
2. `subdomain.domain.com`
3. `sub2.domain.com`

**Folder Structure**

```
public_html 
├── SUBDOMAINS
│   ├── sub2
│   │   ├── assets
│   │   └── src
│   └── subdomain
│       ├── assets
│       └── src
├── assets
├── boot.ts
├── index.html
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── src
└── tsconfig.json
```

I want to be able to utilize the resources of the *root app* and not need to duplicate code.

Comment: What is you angular2 version? How are you packaging your assets? I have the same setup using `webpack`, I will post it if you are interested.

Comment: I am using `System.js` and am running the most recent version of Angular.

Comment: I think you need to use `gulp` for bundling `SystemJS` resources. I haven't done it myself, but [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34616199/3125880). He also uses `jspm`. It's basically the same thing you need you just need to modify the destinations.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @lexith: its stated clearly above, i want to utilize one repo for multiple apps

Comment: when you publish your app/website, you should bunlde it first as @Abdulrahman suggested, and once bundled, you'll not even need the `node_modules`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method to do this is to use **webpack** and **gulp**. You need to use **commonjs** as module in your tsconfig.json.

- Use webpack to pack every individual projects ts files as a bundle.
- With the help of gulp task you can group every project in different
  destination folder.
- Create `index.html` file for each projects destination folder and
  include your `js/ts` bundles in it as scripts.
- Use **webpack dev server** to listen different port for every
  projects index.html file.

  ```
  gulp.task("webpack-dev-serverWeb", function(callback) {
  var myConfig = Object.create(webpackConfig);
  new myWebpackDevServer(mywebpack(myConfig), {
      publicPath: "/" + myConfig.output.publicPath,
      stats: {
          colors: true
      }
  }).listen(8080, "localhost", function(err) {
      if (err) throw new gutil.PluginError("webpack-dev-server", err);
      gutil.log("[webpack-dev-server]", "http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/your_path_to_index.html_for_port_8080/index.html");
  });
  ```