# Correct process for deploying Angular 2 application into production

Tags: angular

I have followed a couple of tutorials regarding the development of Angular 2 applications, but none of them discuss what to do once development is complete.

I have created an application with Typescript and SystemJS, but what are the steps to produce a production-ready package?

My current approach is to check out the files to a new location (without the node_modules folders) and run `npm install --production` then remove the typescript files. I realise this is a horrible way to produce a production-ready package and doesn't contain any minification. I am not familiar with Webpack, SystemJS, gulp, grunt etc... and am looking for pointers in the recommended direction.

Comment: Have you looked at Angular's seed project? They provide webpack (master) and SystemJS branches that both show development and production methods. On the webpack/master branch, run "npm build". https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed

Comment: Here is my recipe for using JSPM to get an angular2 app into production:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34616199/3532945

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time has passed since I asked this question and the [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) now solves this problem:

```
ng build --prod
```

Answer (score 0):

At ng-conf this year, Rob Wormald and Misko presented what looks to be the upcoming official way to deploy applications.  There's a new ***offline compiler*** that preprocesses your app so the user's browser doesn't need to.

The offline compiler inlines all the ES6/ES2015 modules into one file, and then [rollup](http://rollupjs.org/) is used to perform tree-shaking (remove all but what is actually being used).  The result can then be pumped into a minifier to get very small application packages that start *'ridiculously quickly'* (that's how Rob described it).

See the demo here. https://youtu.be/bSssb9AmiJU?t=25m47s