# How to bundle Angular 2 Typescript app using Gulp and SystemJS?

Tags: typescript, angular, gulp, systemjs, jspm

I'm using Typescript with SystemJS for module loading and Gulp for task runner in my Angular 2 project. The current version of Angular in the project is RC2 but the problem is present also with RC1. I followed the steps of brando's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614743/how-to-prepare-release-version-with-systemjs-and-gulp).

After bundling my application and initial load of the website SystemJS throws error:

> Error: http://localhost:57462/app/app.bundle.js detected as register but didn't execute.

The application works but the error in the console definitely is not a good thing.

I tested my configuration on empty project and the problem is present again so I think the problem is in the configuration.

Here it is:

Gulpfile

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
var jspm = require('gulp-jspm-build');

gulp.task('compile:ts', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./appTS/**/*.ts'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(typescript({
                noEmitOnError: true,
                target: 'ES5',
                removeComments: false,
                experimentalDecorators: true,
                emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
                module: 'system',
                moduleResolution: 'node'
            }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/'));
});

gulp.task('copy:vendor', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
        'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js',
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js',
        'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/vendor/'));
});

gulp.task('bundle:app', ['compile:ts'], function () {
    return jspm({
        bundleOptions: {
            minify: true,
            mangle: false
        },
        bundleSfx: true,
        bundles: [
            { src: './app/main.js', dst: 'bundle.js' }
        ]
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/'));
});

gulp.task('bundle', ['bundle:app', 'copy:vendor'], function () {
    return gulp.src([
        './assets/vendor/Reflect.js',
        './assets/vendor/shim.min.js',
        './assets/vendor/zone.min.js',
        './app/bundle.js'])
    .pipe(concat('app.bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/'))
});

gulp.task('default', ['bundle']);
```

```js
var packages = {
    app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    "symbol-observable": { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    "reflect-metadata": { main: 'Reflect.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};

var ngPackageNames = ['common',
                      'compiler',
                      'core',
                      'http',
                      'platform-browser',
                      'platform-browser-dynamic',
                      'router',
                      'router-deprecated',
                      'upgrade'];

ngPackageNames.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    packages['@angular/' + element] = { main: 'bundles/' + element + '.umd.min.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

System.config({
    main: 'dispel.bundle.min',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    format: 'register',
    packages: packages,
    baseURL: "/",
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    transpiler: false,
    paths: {
        "node_modules*": "node_modules*",
        "@angular*": "node_modules/@angular/*"
    },
    map: {
        "@angular": "node_modules/@angular",
        "symbol-observable": "node_modules/symbol-observable",
        "ng2-translate": "node_modules/ng2-translate",
        "es6-shim": "node_modules/es6-shim",
        "reflect-metadata": "node_modules/reflect-metadata",
        "rxjs": "node_modules/rxjs",
        "zone.js": "node_modules/zone.js"
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you create a repo we could clone and test?

Comment: Also, any particular reason you;re using `system`/`register` format? What happens if you use `"module": "commonjs"` in TS compier and `format": "cjs"` in System config?

Comment: There is no particular reason for that. The error is no longer thrown by SystemJS but there was a new error: `crypto.js not found`. I added `"crypto": "node_modules/crypto-js/index.js"` mapping in System.config -> map section and everything works but SystemJS makes separate requests for every one of crypto-js files (around 30).

Comment: @Sasxa can you post an answer

Comment: I am using this starter, that does everything you wanted and more:
https://github.com/antonybudianto/angular2-starter The gulp file is nicely divided to separate tasks, and very easy to manage.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried using [SystemJS Builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder) in your `bundle:app` gulp task instead of jspm?

Below is a simplified version of how to bundle Tour of Heroes running 2.0.0-rc.1 ([source](https://github.com/smmorneau/tour-of-heroes/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L63), [live example](https://tour-of-heroes-typescript.herokuapp.com/)).

**gulpfile.js**

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
var systemjsBuilder = require('systemjs-builder');

// Compile TypeScript app to JS
gulp.task('compile:ts', function () {
  return gulp
    .src([
        "appTS/**/*.ts",
        "typings/*.d.ts"
    ])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(typescript({
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "app",
        "target": "ES5"
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});

// Generate systemjs-based bundle (app/app.js)
gulp.task('bundle:app', function() {
  var builder = new systemjsBuilder('public', './system.config.js');
  return builder.buildStatic('app', 'app/app.js');
});

// Copy and bundle dependencies into one file (vendor/vendors.js)
// system.config.js can also bundled for convenience
gulp.task('bundle:vendor', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
        'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
        'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js',
        'system.config.js',
      ])
        .pipe(concat('vendors.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor'));
});

// Copy dependencies loaded through SystemJS into dir from node_modules
gulp.task('copy:vendor', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
        'node_modules/@angular/**/*'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor'));
});

gulp.task('vendor', ['bundle:vendor', 'copy:vendor']);
gulp.task('app', ['compile:ts', 'bundle:app']);

// Bundle dependencies and app into one file (app.bundle.js)
gulp.task('bundle', ['vendor', 'app'], function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'app/app.js',
        'vendor/vendors.js'
        ])
    .pipe(concat('app.bundle.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['bundle']);
```

**system.config.js**

```js
var map = {
  'app':                                'app',
  'rxjs':                               'vendor/rxjs',
  'zonejs':                             'vendor/zone.js',
  'reflect-metadata':                   'vendor/reflect-metadata',
  '@angular':                           'vendor/@angular'
};

var packages = {
  'app':                                { main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'rxjs':                               { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'zonejs':                             { main: 'zone', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'reflect-metadata':                   { main: 'Reflect', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};

var packageNames = [
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/router-deprecated',
  '@angular/testing',
  '@angular/upgrade',
];

packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
  packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

System.config({
  map: map,
  packages: packages
});
```

Comment: how to use app.bundle.js created by gulp?

Comment: I am going out of the way but really need help to put everything together. Your gulp file is the only worked for me so far. how to use app.bundle.js created by gulp? I don't see anywhere in your gulpfile.ts that your copying index.html.

Comment: @DarshanPuranik You shouldn't need to copy index.html, and you can just include app.bundle.js in index.html. Some of the file names may be slightly different, but essentially the same strategy can be found here: https://github.com/smmorneau/tour-of-heroes

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the example with the inlining, that was the missing link in my gulpfile :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could help:

```
System.config({
  "meta": {
    "app.bundle.js": {
      "format": "register"
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: No, unfortunately doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to bundle for production using `gulp` and `Angular 2.4` but all the examples had blocking issues; even `git clone`ing the working examples didn't work. I finally got it to work by using [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) and copying my files there. It turns out the dependencies were easily manageable compared to using `SystemJS` where you have to add to `system.config.js` and hoping that dependencies followed the patterns `SystemJS` wants.

Answer (score -2):

By Using Gulp we can bundle our project but i sugest ng build or npm build for bundling keep gulp only for task runners