# vendor bundle + systemjs

Tags: typescript, webpack, bundle, systemjs

I have a systemjs build for a typescript web project.  There are a lot of tiny files from 3rd party dependencies - i've bundled those up using webpack into a `vendor.bundle.js` file.  I just want to use systemjs to load up and transpile my project typescript files + angular2 and load the 3rd party deps with a single load of the vendor bundle.  That will minimize the number of rest calls and make page refreshing much quicker as i develop.  Currently, I load the bundle in my index.html with `<script src="scripts/vendor.bundle.js"></script>`, but systemjs still tries to import 3rd party deps via individual rest calls.  any idea how to get systemjs to respect the vendor bundle?

E.g. In my vendor bundle i have things like bootstrap.js, but systemjs will still try to load it when running `import 'bootstrap';` giving me a 404: `https://localhost:8081/bootstrap.js 404 ()`

Here's the Systemjs config:

`{
    "transpiler": "typescript",
    "defaultJSExtension": false,
    "map": {
        "app": "./scripts",
        "@angular": "node_modules/@angular",
        "rxjs": "node_modules/rxjs",

    },
    "packages": {
        "app": {
            "defaultExtension": "ts",
            "main": "main"
        },
        "rxjs": {
            "main": "Rx.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/common": {
            "main": "/bundles/common.umd.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/compiler": {
            "main": "/bundles/compiler.umd.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/core": {
            "main": "/bundles/core.umd.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/forms": {
            "main": "/bundles/forms.umd.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/http": {
            "main": "/bundles/http.umd.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/platform-browser": {
            "main": "/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": {
            "main": "/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
        "@angular/router": {
            "main": "/bundles/router.umd.js",
            "defaultExtension": "js"
        }
    },
    "typescriptOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "tsconfig": true
    },
    "meta": {
        "typescript": {
            "exports": "ts"
        }
    },
    "defaultJSExtensions": true
}`

Comment: i abandoned systemjs and now just do my dev work using webpack + awesome `awesome-typescript-loader` and `CommonsChunkPlugin` and the watch option and it works a million times better

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862457/how-to-bundle-angular-2-typescript-app-using-gulp-and-systemjs