# How do I actually create a distributional app from Angular 2 RC4 + Typescript + systemjs app?

Tags: angular

There's a quickstarter tutorial over at angular.io which uses typescript & systemjs.

Could someone share their build process with this setup (Angular 2 RC4, TypeScript)

Answer (score 1):

You can begin from Modular starter (seed) project for Angular 2 apps with fast, statically typed build

https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

Answer (score 1):

I have created an small app doing all CRUD operations in Angular 2 RC4 using TypeScript. You can view my source [here](https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet) on Github, If this may fulfill your need. Please feel free to ask any questions if having issues.

> **Repostitory:** https://github.com/khanstudio-github/Angular2AppASPNet

**Prerequisite:**

- ***Node.Js v4.4.7*** (can download from **`www.nodejs.org/en`**)